# How can I solve the errors and warnings of this simple MQL4 trade bot and make it work?

Tags: mql4

I try to create a simple trade bot in MetaTrader4 with MQL4 and with the help of AI I provide this code:

```
#property strict

// Input parameters
input double lotSize = 0.1;
input int maPeriod = 50;
input double riskPercentage = 2.0;
input int rsiPeriod = 14;
input int macdPeriod = 12;
input int macdSignalPeriod = 9;
input int bollingerPeriod = 20;
input int bollingerDevFactor = 2;
input double maxRiskPerTrade = 1.0;
input double maxDrawdown = 10.0;
input int maxConsecutiveLosses = 3;
input int maxTradesPerDay = 5;
input double atrMultiplier = 2.0;
input double trailingStopMultiplier = 1.0;

// Global variables
double maValue;
double currentPrice;
double rsiValue;
double macdValue;
double bollingerUpper;
double bollingerLower;
double stopLossPrice;
double takeProfitPrice;
double riskPerLot;
int maxLots;
double trailingStopPrice;

int maHandle;
int rsiHandle;
int macdHandle;
int bollingerHandle;

double accountBalance;
double riskAmount;
double atr;
double trailingStopDistance;

int consecutiveLosses;
int tradesToday;

int OnInit()
{
   // Initialize moving average
   maHandle = iMA(Symbol(), 0, maPeriod, 0, MODE_SMA, PRICE_CLOSE);
   
   // Initialize RSI
   rsiHandle = iRSI(Symbol(), 0, rsiPeriod, PRICE_CLOSE);
   
   // Initialize MACD
   macdHandle = iMACD(Symbol(), 0, macdPeriod, macdSignalPeriod, 0, PRICE_CLOSE);
   
   // Initialize Bollinger Bands
   bollingerHandle = iBands(Symbol(), 0, bollingerPeriod, bollingerDevFactor, 0, 0);
   
   // Calculate risk amount
   riskAmount = AccountBalance() * riskPercentage / 100.0;
   
   // Initialize global variables
   accountBalance = AccountBalance();
   consecutiveLosses = 0;
   tradesToday = 0;
   
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

void OnTick()
{
   maValue = iMA(Symbol(), 0, maPeriod, 0, MODE_SMA, PRICE_CLOSE, 1);
   currentPrice = MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_BID);
   rsiValue = iRSI(Symbol(), 0, rsiPeriod, PRICE_CLOSE);
   macdValue = iMACD(Symbol(), 0, macdPeriod, macdSignalPeriod, 0, 0);
   bollingerUpper = iBands(Symbol(), 0, bollingerPeriod, bollingerDevFactor, 0, 1);
   bollingerLower = iBands(Symbol(), 0, bollingerPeriod, bollingerDevFactor, 0, 2);
   
   // Calculate ATR and trailing stop distance
   atr = iATR(Symbol(), 0, 14);
   trailingStopDistance = atr * trailingStopMultiplier;
   
   // Check if maximum drawdown has been exceeded
   if((AccountBalance() - accountBalance) / accountBalance * 100.0 < -maxDrawdown)
   {
      Print("Maximum drawdown exceeded. Trading halted.");
      return;
   }
   
   // Check if maximum consecutive losses has been reached
   if(consecutiveLosses >= maxConsecutiveLosses)
   {
      Print("Maximum consecutive losses reached. Trading halted.");
      return;
   }
   
   // Check if maximum trades per day has been reached
   if(tradesToday >= maxTradesPerDay)
   {
      Print("Maximum trades per day reached. Trading halted.");
      return;
   }
   
   // Open buy trade if price crosses above MA and RSI is oversold
   if(currentPrice > maValue && rsiValue < 30.0)
   {
      stopLossPrice = currentPrice - atr * atrMultiplier;
      takeProfitPrice = currentPrice + atr * atrMultiplier;
      riskPerLot = atr * atrMultiplier * lotSize;
      maxLots = (int)(riskAmount / riskPerLot);
      
      // Check if MACD is above the signal line and Bollinger bands are not too far apart
      if(macdValue > iMACD(Symbol(), 0, macdPeriod, macdSignalPeriod, 0, 0, 1) && bollingerUpper - bollingerLower > 2.0 * Point)
      {
         // Check if maximum risk per trade has been exceeded
         if(riskPerLot * lotSize / AccountBalance() * 100.0 > maxRiskPerTrade)
         {
            Print("Maximum risk per trade exceeded. Skipping trade.");
            return;
         }
         
         if(maxLots > 0)
         {
            trailingStopPrice = currentPrice - trailingStopDistance;
            int ticket = OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_BUY, lotSize, currentPrice, 3, stopLossPrice, takeProfitPrice, "Buy order", 0, 0, Green);
            tradesToday++;

            if(ticket > 0)
            {
               // Set trailing stop loss
               double initialStopLoss = stopLossPrice;
               while(OrderSelect(ticket, SELECT_BY_TICKET))
               {
                  double currentProfit = OrderProfit();
                  double currentStopLoss = OrderStopLoss();
                  
                  if(currentProfit > 0 && currentStopLoss < currentPrice - trailingStopDistance)
                  {
                     double newStopLoss = currentPrice - trailingStopDistance;
                     if(newStopLoss > initialStopLoss)
                     {
                        if(OrderModify(ticket, OrderOpenPrice(), newStopLoss, takeProfitPrice, 0, Green))
                        {
                           initialStopLoss = newStopLoss;
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
   
   // Close buy trade if price falls below entry price plus a certain percentage
   if(OrderType() == OP_BUY && currentPrice < (OrderOpenPrice() - (OrderOpenPrice() * 0.05)))
   {
      stopLossPrice = 0;
      takeProfitPrice = 0;
      riskPerLot = 0;
      maxLots = 0;
      trailingStopPrice = currentPrice + trailingStopDistance;
      if(OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), stopLossPrice, takeProfitPrice, 0))
      {
         consecutiveLosses = OrderProfit() < 0 ? consecutiveLosses + 1 : 0;
      }
   }
}

void OnTrade()
{
   // Check if trade was closed with a loss
   if(OrderSelect(0, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_HISTORY) && (OrderType() == OP_SELL || OrderType() == OP_BUY))
   {
      if(OrderProfit() < 0)
      {
         consecutiveLosses++;
      }
      else
      {
         consecutiveLosses = 0;
      }

      // Calculate dynamic take profit based on ATR and current price movement
      double currentPrice = MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_BID);
      double takeProfitPrice = currentPrice + (atr * atrMultiplier * 1.5);

      // Check if the order is a buy order and take profit price is higher than the current take profit
      if(OrderType() == OP_BUY && takeProfitPrice > OrderTakeProfit())
      {
         OrderModify(OrderTicket(), OrderOpenPrice(), takeProfitPrice, OrderStopLoss(), 0, Green);
      }
   }
}

void OnTimer()
{
   // Reset trades today counter at midnight
   if(TimeHour(TimeCurrent()) == 0 && TimeMinute(TimeCurrent()) == 0)
   {
      tradesToday = 0;
   }
}
```

when I want to run it I got these warnings and errors:

```
'Moving Average.mq4'    Moving Average.mq4  1   1
'iMA' - wrong parameters count  Moving Average.mq4  48  15
possible loss of data due to type conversion    Moving Average.mq4  48  13
'iRSI' - wrong parameters count Moving Average.mq4  51  16
possible loss of data due to type conversion    Moving Average.mq4  51  14
'iMACD' - wrong parameters count    Moving Average.mq4  54  17
possible loss of data due to type conversion    Moving Average.mq4  54  15
'iBands' - wrong parameters count   Moving Average.mq4  57  22
possible loss of data due to type conversion    Moving Average.mq4  57  20
'iRSI' - wrong parameters count Moving Average.mq4  74  15
'iMACD' - wrong parameters count    Moving Average.mq4  75  16
'iBands' - wrong parameters count   Moving Average.mq4  76  21
'iBands' - wrong parameters count   Moving Average.mq4  77  21
'iATR' - wrong parameters count Moving Average.mq4  80  10
'iMACD' - wrong parameters count    Moving Average.mq4  113 22
possible loss of data due to type conversion    Moving Average.mq4  162 64
declaration of 'currentPrice' hides global variable Moving Average.mq4  184 14
   see previous declaration of 'currentPrice'   Moving Average.mq4  21  8
declaration of 'takeProfitPrice' hides global variable  Moving Average.mq4  185 14
   see previous declaration of 'takeProfitPrice'    Moving Average.mq4  27  8
return value of 'OrderModify' should be checked Moving Average.mq4  190 10
```

I'm unable to solve these issues because I'm amateur and I don't have sufficient knowledge to solve these, if anyone can help me, please help, I really need his/her help.